# Using loop devices in docker without --privileged flag

Tags: docker, lvm

Is there any way to use loop devices within docker container without switching on a privileged mode. It looks like there should be a way with adding capabilities, but even when I run container with flag `--cap-add=ALL` I still get an error when I execute `losetup -f` command:

`[root@176f9063d3bb /]# losetup -f
losetup: Could not find any loop device. Maybe this kernel does not know
       about the loop device? (If so, recompile or 'modprobe loop'.)`

Answer (score 0):

you can use add cap and enabled the specific device to use this :

```
docker run -td --cap-add SYS_ADMIN  --device /dev/loop0 --device /dev/loop-control
```